# Outer Join returning NULL even when value present

Tags: null, sql-server-2012, outer-join

I'm trying to create a table where i can see an airport code and its corresponding country and region etc.

I have compiled a table with all the airport codes, countries, and regions; however i seem to be getting  some null values back (even though i know they are included in the joined table.

for instance the airport code 'HKG' will pull 'Hong Kong' for a row and then all of the sudden in another row (which is also 'HKG') it joins the country as NULL instead of Hong Kong....

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Here is my join:

```
     FROM
      [dbo].[GS_TB_2G] [Data]
             Left Outer JOIN [dbo].[Gateway_Detail] [OrigC]
                ON [Data].[OrigGateway] = [OrigC].[code]
             Left Outer JOIN [dbo].[Gateway_Detail] [DestC]
                ON [Data].[DestGateway] = [DestC].[code]
            --Left Outer JOIN [dbo].[AWB_SECT_INFO] [Carrier]
            --  ON [Data].[awb_seq] = [Carrier].[awb_seq]
```

The full Query is seen below

```
        set @report_yr = 2014 --Enter the Year you wish to run the report for
        set @report_Mth = 12  --Enter the Month you wish to run the report for

        SELECT
         Table1.[awb_prefix],
         Table1.[Origin],
         Table1.[Origin_2],
         Table1.[Origin_3],
         [Origin_4] = 'WW',
         Table1.[Destination],
         Table1.[Destination_2],
         Table1.[Destination_3],
         [Destination_4] = 'WW',
         Table1.[Mth],
         Table1.[yr],
         Table1.[Customer],
         sum (Table1.[Gross_Rev]) as [Gr Revenue],
         sum (Table1.[CHW]) as [Ch Weight]

        FROM (
         SELECT
          CASE
            WHEN [Data].[OrigGateway] IS NULL THEN [Data].[overall_orig] ELSE [Data].[OrigGateway]
          END AS [Origin],
          [OrigC].[country] AS [origin_2],
          [OrigC].[region] AS [origin_3],
          CASE
            WHEN [Data].[DestGateway] IS NULL THEN [Data].[overall_dest] ELSE [Data].[DestGateway]
          END AS [Destination],
          [DestC].[country] AS [Destination_2],
          CASE 
            WHEN [DestC].[region] IS NULL THEN 'OTHER' ELSE [DestC].[region] 
          END AS [destination_3],
          [Data].[Mth],
          [Data].[yr],
          [Data].[Forwarder] AS [Customer],
          CASE
            WHEN [Data].[Cal_Gross_Revenue] <0 THEN 0 ELSE [Data].[Cal_Gross_Revenue]
          END AS [Gross_Rev],
          [Data].[charge_weight] AS [CHW],
          CASE
            WHEN LEFT([Data].[AirWayBill] , 3) in ('403','369') THEN LEFT([Data].[AirWayBill],3) ELSE 'OTHER'
          END AS [awb_prefix]

         FROM
          [dbo].[GS_TB_2G] [Data]
                 Left Outer JOIN [dbo].[Gateway_Detail] [OrigC]
                    ON [Data].[OrigGateway] = [OrigC].[code]
                 Left Outer JOIN [dbo].[Gateway_Detail] [DestC]
                    ON [Data].[DestGateway] = [DestC].[code]
                --Left Outer JOIN [dbo].[AWB_SECT_INFO] [Carrier]
                --  ON [Data].[awb_seq] = [Carrier].[awb_seq]
         WHERE 
            [IATA_code] NOT IN ('0508634','0514616')
            AND (
                    ([mth] between 1 and @report_Mth AND [yr] = @report_yr)
                    OR ((@report_Mth < 4) AND [Mth] between 9+@report_Mth and 12 AND [yr] = @report_yr-1)
                )
            --AND (
            --      ([Carrier].[carrier] in ('PO','3S','9S','K4','5Y','Y8') AND LEFT([Data].[AirWayBill] , 3) in ('403','369'))
            --      OR ([Carrier].[carrier] in ('PO'))
            --  )
        ) AS Table1

        Group By
         [awb_prefix],
         [Customer],
         [yr],
         [Mth],
         [Origin],
         [Origin_2],
         [origin_3],
         [destination],
         [destination_2],
         [destination_3]
```

Comment: Are there any stray characters in your code field?  Spaces, nulls, etc. can interfere with a join.  Try casting the missing records to `varbinary()`.  Are the characters different case and you're using a case-sensitive collation?

Comment: No they are both char(3) and all have only three capital letters. also it is matching on some rows and not others for the same value.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know much about your data, so please give a try by replacing your JOINs with the following and see if that works?

```
FROM
      [dbo].[GS_TB_2G] [Data]
             Left Outer JOIN [dbo].[Gateway_Detail] [OrigC]
                ON RTRIM(LTRIM(CAST(REPLACE([Data].[OrigGateway] COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN, CHAR(0), '') AS VARCHAR(100)))) = RTRIM(LTRIM(CAST(REPLACE([OrigC].[code] COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN, CHAR(0), '') AS VARCHAR(100))))
             Left Outer JOIN [dbo].[Gateway_Detail] [DestC]
                ON RTRIM(LTRIM(CAST(REPLACE([Data].[DestGateway] COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN, CHAR(0), '') AS VARCHAR(100)))) = RTRIM(LTRIM(CAST(REPLACE([DestC].[code] COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN, CHAR(0), '') AS VARCHAR(100))))
            --Left Outer JOIN [dbo].[AWB_SECT_INFO] [Carrier]
            --  ON [Data].[awb_seq] = [Carrier].[awb_seq]
```

Comment: Would you be able to provide some data or build you schema and data on [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) so it would be easy to work with?

Comment: I actually figured it out.. really simple issue actually. I had added that 'is null then' statement for 'origin' early on under select, and what was happening was the origin only looked not null because the 'is null then' statement was replacing the null values with overall destination.  i simply moved the join down after Table1 was completed so that i was joining table1.origin instead of data.origin